# Servo connected to PIC does not work

Tags: pic, servo

I have a [PIC 12F629](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/41190G.pdf) and I connected it to my servo ([TowerPro sg5010 motor](http://www.servodatabase.com/servo/towerpro/sg-5010)) per these details:

- PIC pin 1 to positive
- pin 8 to negative
- pin 2 to servo red wire (signal)
- servo brown wire to negative
- servo orange to positive (servo has three colors: brown, red and orange wires)

I programmed PIC with this code:

```
    #include <xc.h>
    #define _XTAL_FREQ 20000000
    #pragma config WDTE=OFF , BOREN=OFF , PWRTE=ON , MCLRE=OFF , FOSC=INTRCIO

    void main(){
    TRISIO = 0b0000000;
    GPIO = 0b000000;
        while(1==1){
            GPIO = 0b000000;
            __delay_ms(1);
            GPIO = 0b111111;
            __delay_ms(19);
        }

}
```

But servo does not move a bit. What is the problem?

**Edit**: i found out it rotate servo arm very fast to its end(the point it couldn't rotate any more then it sound like tick tick tick .....)

i changed my code to this(to reverse it back):

```
            GPIO = 0b000000;
            __delay_ms(1);
            GPIO = 0b111111;
            __delay_ms(19);
            GPIO = 0b000000;
            __delay_ms(2);
            GPIO = 0b111111;
            __delay_ms(18);
```

but it behave the same.

Comment: red is usually positive....

Comment: I checked the link you gave for the servo, but there's no datasheet.  There's not even a wiring diagram on there.  Please add some links showing us where you're getting your wiring information from.  Also, Electronics has a really cool circuit diagram tool.  Try drawing something for us to look at.  That'll help with debugging.

Answer (score 2):

A few things:

1. Your output pulse is inverted. Swap your GPIO commands to write a "1" for the short pulse, and "0" for the remaining time in your 20ms loop.
2. You have the red and orange wires swapped. The red wire goes to the pos supply voltage. The orange wire is your control. The brown wire is DC common (negative lead from power supply).
3. Check the accuracy of your __delay_ms() routine. The XC8 compiler uses the _XTAL_FREQ constant for the delay routines. The internal oscillator of the PIC12F629 runs at 4Mhz (not 20Mhz). You should redefine _XTAL_FREQ to 4000000.
4. In your second example, you have not allowed enough time in between commands for the motor to move. Try running your 1ms high / 19 ms low loop for maybe a second, and then switch to a loop that is 2ms high / 18ms low. Run the second loop for maybe a second, then return to the first loop. Try this:

   ```
   #include <xc.h>
   #define _XTAL_FREQ 4000000
   #pragma config WDTE=OFF , BOREN=OFF , PWRTE=ON , MCLRE=OFF , FOSC=INTRCIO

   void main(){
   int i;
   TRISIO = 0b0000000;
   GPIO = 0b000000;
       while(1==1){
           for(i=0;i<50;i++){
               GPIO = 0b111111;
               __delay_ms(1);
               GPIO = 0b000000;
               __delay_ms(19);
           }
           for(i=0;i<50;i++){
               GPIO = 0b111111;
               __delay_ms(2);
               GPIO = 0b000000;
               __delay_ms(18);
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: i changed servo wire and connect brown to ground and red to pos and i change the code to what you said and i changed _XTAL_FREQ but it clicking when pic send pulse to it.

Comment: Do you have access to an oscilloscope? It would be helpful to see if your PWM control pulses are as expected.

Comment: Since you other question was marked as a duplicate, I will repeat a couple comments here: 1) In your other question you had defined _XTAL_FREQ as 40000000 , this is incorrect, it should be 4000000 (in other words you had defined it as 40Mhz instead of 4Mhz). A correct value for _XTAL_FREQ is necessary for the delay routines to work correctly. 2) If you do not have an oscilloscope to check the accuracy of your delay routines, try writing a simple program that will toggle your LED every second. This will provide quick feedback that your processor is running and at the expected speed.

Comment: A couple other things to notice: 1) If you are wondering why all the focus on the accuracy of _XTAL_FREQ, it is necessary for the servo to work correctly that the PWM period be 20ms and the PWM pulse width range from around 0.9ms to 2.1ms. 2) Notice in my example above, the first for loop creates a stream of 1ms pulses every 20ms for 1 second (50 pulses); while the second loop creates a stream of 2ms pulses every 20ms for 1 second. These pulses need to run for as long as it takes the servo to go from one position the the next. I chose 1 second to be sure to allow enough time.

Answer (score 1):

https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-arduino-lesson-14-servo-motors/the-breadboard-layout-for-sweep ....

quote ...The servo motor has three leads. The color of the leads varies between servo motors, but the red lead is always 5V and GND will either be black or brown. The other lead is the control lead and this is usually orange or yellow. ....