# Servo doesn't move when driven by a PIC micro controller

Tags: pic, servo, robotics

I have a [PIC12F629](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/41190G.pdf) and a servo [sg5010](http://www.servodatabase.com/servo/towerpro/sg-5010)(for which I could not found any datasheet ) 
So I built this circuit :

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fWrF8t.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The LED is for checking if a pulse is sent and the switch SW1 is for enabling the servo.

And I have written this program for the PIC:

```
#include <xc.h>
#define _XTAL_FREQ 40000000
#pragma config WDTE=OFF , BOREN=OFF , PWRTE=ON , MCLRE=OFF , FOSC=INTRCIO

void main(){
    TRISIO = 0b0000000;
    GPIO = 0b000000;
    int i;
    while(1==1){

            GPIO = 0b111111;
            __delay_ms(1);
            GPIO = 0b000000;
            __delay_ms(19);

        for(i=0;i<50;i++){

        }

            GPIO = 0b111111;
            __delay_ms(2);
            GPIO = 0b000000;
            __delay_ms(18);

        for(i=0;i<50;i++){

        }
    }

}
```

Here I tried to turn the servo arm any degrees forward and backward and the **for loop** is here to give time for the servo to act and **_XTAL_FREQ** is here to set its frequency.

I even tried to transfer the GPIO settings into the **for loops** and add an empty **for loop** after them.

When I run the circuit, I face critical problems:

1. When I press the switch, the servo reverses about 10 degree back and forward (every time it powers on even without any feedback connected). Then if it doesn't reach 360 degree, it turns 20 degrees by 20 degrees up to the end and then stops and emit sounds like click click for every pulse sent by the PIC. (I saw LED blinks). This is not what I want to implement.
2. If I delete every loop in it (for and while loops) and only write this in main:

   ```
   GPIO = 0b111111;
   __delay_ms(2);
   GPIO = 0b000000;
   __delay_ms(18);
   ```

The program loops on itself and the LED blinks. Why does it loop on itself?

Comment: @David it changed a lot and i add and change circuit, and that one lead nowhere.i will delete that one.

Comment: This is a modified version of the [changes I suggested yesterday](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/111144/25328). The intent of my changes was to run the 1 ms pulse continuously for 1 second, then the 2 ms pulse continuously for 1 second, and then loop back. The intent was to have the servo switch from one position to another each second. I don't know if it will work by sending the pulse only once instead of continuously; but if you wish to preserve the 1 second delays, either insert __delay_ms(20) within the for loops, or replace the for loops with __delay_ms(1000).

Comment: For your final design, if you include a delay to allow time for the motor to get to it's position, you can then turn off the PWM to the motor. There is no need for the switch.

Comment: If you do not have an oscilloscope to check the accuracy of your delay routines, try writing a simple routine that will toggle your LED every second. This will provide quick feedback that your processor is running and at the expected speed.

Comment: By the way, you have incorporated every suggestion I made yesterday and now you wish to delete that question as though it did not happen. Did you not find my answer useful at all? Good luck on your project, I'm done.

Comment: Ok, one more comment and then I'm done .... You have defined _XTAL_FREQ as 40000000 , this is incorrect, it should be 4000000 . You have defined it as 40Mhz instead of 4Mhz.

Comment: @Tut,please don't get angry, your answer was helpful and gave me a lot of good information but i think to change the question to make it more clear. with a lot of change i think it is good to ask a new one.

Comment: Ok, but please understand that no-one here gets paid. The only reward is through up-votes and accepted answers. You have now asked 5 questions on this site and receive much help from many people, and yet you have not up-voted or accepted any answers. It is not required, but it is considered the polite thing to do.

Comment: @Tut, i understand that sir.those are concurrent projects that i will definitely vote theme up and accept one answer,but non of theme solve my problem and i currently face some personal issues,as soon as i get ride of that problems i came back and appreciate those answer and i will do the right thing.

Answer (score 0):

For the first question, your "for loops" do nothing. I know that they are here to add delays, but there is a high chance that the compiler removes them completely because they are not doing anything for it.
To remedy this, add a **volatile** keyword on your i variable. This would tell the compiler not to optimize things related to the i variable, such as your delay loops.
This could be the issue.

And why no using a __delay_ms() function here, instead of a for loop?

For your second question:

the program loops on itself because the MCU would some kind of reset when your main function returns.

Thus it will run your main again and reset, and run again, and reset, ....

Comment: Executing a nop in the loop is perhaps better than marking a variable volatile unnecessarily.

Comment: Not unnecessarily, but in order to avoid optimization. Volatile is here also for this. It's more a tricks to add an asm NOP into the loop than using the std C volatile keyword.

Comment: The volatile keyword tells the compiler a variable can change value externally (e.g. an input port or other memory mapped device).  It isn't really intended as a magic "don't optimise this code", for which some compilers have an `optimize` pragma.

Comment: Thinking of your example here: what you are intending to write in the high level code is "do nothing" and you want to do it enough times to make a delay.  This is a perfect use of a NOP and a loop.  Don't "trick" the compiler with a particular keyword just because it has a useful side effect.